# How to move from one game scene to another?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, xna

Hello I am new to XNA and Now I am developing a game.
For that I chose a Silverlight+XNA project. Now I have a GamePage.xaml and .cs file with some images. Now I want to create the second scene. How to add this new Page and navigate to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to manage multiple screens in a game is to implement a Screen Manager. This will essentially act as the central event caller, to which you can plug in screen classes when you want them to become active.

There is a good example of this on the App Hub.

[Example of Screen Management on AppHub in XNA](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management)

EDIT:

If you wish to create a standard XAML page, this is as simple as right-clicking on your project and choosing Add -> New Item... and selecting "Windows Phone Portrait/Landscape Page".

To navigate to the page, you will want to use the NavigationService class as follows:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```